# Cordova Detect user already login Firebase

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication

I Was wondering if there's a way to detect if the user is already login with firebase and redirect to a certain page.

I'm using this firebase method

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
      location.href = 'feed.html';
   } else {
      location.href = 'login.html';
   }
});
```

But if I put this code in index.js function(deviceready) it keep refreshing the page.

In swift I would put this control in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but I don't find anything similar in Cordova.

Can you help me out?

Comment: After you redirect to feed.html or login.html, you don't need to redirect to both paged. In feed.html if the user is logged in, do nothing. In login.html, if the user is not logged in, do nothing.

Comment: Ok perfect. But I'm calling this function in my index.js. Should I do it in the first page? Because I want to call it Immediately and if  i call it in one page I got an annoying glich show me the page before redirect.